# JFuzzyLogic gives error in Eclipse IDE while code working well with another IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, jfuzzylogic

While the same code **working in NetBeans IDE** It gives this error on eclipse ! I'm getting this error after running the code and giving the input

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> net/sourceforge/jFuzzyLogic/FIS   at
> pkt.Resturant.(Resturant.java:17)   at
> pkt.Program.main(Program.java:15) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jFuzzyLogic.FIS     at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
> ... 2 more

**Resturant.java** file

```
package pkt;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import net.sourceforge.jFuzzyLogic.FIS;

public class Resturant {
    private FIS fis;
    private double servis;
    private double yemek;

    public Resturant(double servis, double yemek) throws URISyntaxException {
        this.servis = servis;
        this.yemek = yemek;
        File dosya = new File(getClass().getResource("Model.fcl").toURI());
        fis = FIS.load(dosya.getPath(), true);
        fis.setVariable("servis", servis);
        fis.setVariable("yemek", yemek);
        fis.evaluate();
    }

    public Resturant() throws URISyntaxException {
        File dosya = new File(getClass().getResource("Model.fcl").toURI());
        fis = FIS.load(dosya.getPath(), true);
    }

    public FIS getModel() {
        return fis;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String cikti = "servis: " + servis + "\nYemek: " + yemek + "\nTur: " + fis.getVariable("tur").getValue();
        return cikti;
    }
}
```

**Program.java** file

```
package pkt;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import net.sourceforge.jFuzzyLogic.plot.JFuzzyChart;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Servis (0-9): ");
        double servis = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Yemek (0-9): ");
        double yemek = in.nextDouble();
        try {
            Resturant r = new Resturant(servis,yemek);
                        System.out.print(r);
        } catch(URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**And the JFuzzyLogic file Model.fcl**

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK model

VAR_INPUT
    servis : REAL;
    yemek : REAL;
END_VAR

VAR_OUTPUT
    tur : REAL;
END_VAR

FUZZIFY servis
    TERM kotu := (0,1)(4,0);
    TERM iyi := (1,0)(4,1)(6,1)(9,0);
    TERM mukemmel := (6,0)(9,1);
END_FUZZIFY

FUZZIFY yemek
    TERM kotu := (0,1)(3,1)(6,0);
    TERM lezzetli := (4,0)(9,1);
END_FUZZIFY

DEFUZZIFY tur
    TERM ucuz := (0,1)(20,1)(50,0);
    TERM orta := (40,0)(60,1)(80,0);
    TERM iyi := (70,0)(85,1)(100,0);
    METHOD : COG;
    DEFAULT := 0;
END_DEFUZZIFY

RULEBLOCK kuralblock1
    AND : MIN;
    ACT : MIN;
    ACCU : MAX;
    
    RULE 1 : IF servis IS kotu OR yemek IS kotu THEN tur IS ucuz;
    RULE 2 : IF servis IS iyi THEN tur IS orta;
    RULE 3 : IF servis IS mukemmel AND yemek IS lezzetli THEN tur IS iyi;
    
END_RULEBLOCK

END_FUNCTION_BLOCK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem is, It's the way of adding the FazzyLogic library!
Instead of adding it to the Classpath I added it to the Modulepath!
I've no experience with java neither eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0):

All I can do at this point is point out the information you haven't provided, which would tell us what the problem is.  Your project has source code, like the class "Restaurant", but it also has dependencies, like class "net.sourceforge.jFuzzyLogic.FIS".  The latter class is not included in your project, it has to be specified as a dependency. There are several ways that Eclipse projects can specify dependencies, and they have to be done carefully.

We don't know how you have specified the dependency on that class "net.sourceforge.jFuzzyLogic.FIS", or even if you have at all.  You could be using Maven to build your project, which would imply that you're using the "m2e" Eclipse plugin.  You could also be using Ant, although I doubt it.  You could also be using no build system at all, which means you must have intended to store the jar file containing that class directly in a subdirectory of your project, and specified a direct dependency on that jar.

We also don't know how you're running the project.  It's most likely that you're running it directly in Eclipse, but I could be wrong.